# HTTP Post multiple arrays of values PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, http, post

I am looking to see if this is possible.

I am looking to post a an array of multiple values to a server using PHP as a middleware. I have a mobile app where the user will complete a questionnaire. I am wanting to post the question, answer and date for each question in one api call.

Is it possible to POST and deal with an array of values. Something like answers = [[question,answer,date],[question,answer,date],[question,answer,date],[question,answer,date]]

Any thoughts or best practices please do post below.

Update: if possible can you an example or link would be fab!

Comment: @JvdBerg BE HELPFUL. I'd vote down that answer if I could.

Comment: Thanks - can you provide an example or link to how i would achieve it?

Comment: POST is an array, use a multidimensional array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a couple of different ways.  The first way would be to post an array and access it like so:

```
foreach($_POST['answers'] as $answer){

    $thisQuestion = $answer['question'];
    $thisAnswer =   $answer['answer'];
    $thisDate =     $answer['date'];

    // Do something with this current Question/Answer/Date combo
}
```

The second way would be to send a `json` string and to decode it in PHP:

```
$answers = json_decode($_POST['answer']);
```

The method you choose really comes down to which way it is easiest for you to send the data.

Comment: Great answer. The json answer is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Check this O'Really Array manuals for PHP..It really helps me a lot for programing with Arrays.

[Link](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html)

Comment: here OP need to change something in the client side such as the way he sends the data / naming of the HTML elements but providing a link of how array works it looks kind of irrelevant to me. He is not asking how array works here as far as i understood.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest/hackiest way would be to just put a number on each set and parse it out that way. In other words, don't actually pass an array but rather values as such:
[question0,answer0,date0],[question1,answer1,date1], etc.
Other options include passing arrays for each option (I believe you can do that), pass JSON (www.json.org) or serialization of your array which is a bit more complicated. Hopefully one of those three will help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yup , you can definitely achieve this. Try the code snippet below :

```
<?php

if($_POST) {
    echo $_POST ['questions'][1];
    echo $_POST ['questions'][2];
    var_dump($_POST);
}

else {

?>


<form method="post">
    <input type = "text" name = "questions[2]">
    <input type = "text" name= "questions[1]">
    <input type="submit" name = "submit" value "Submit">
</form>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Now if you submit `world` in the fist text input and `hello` in 2nd input , you will see `helloworld` as the way i echoed it.

Even you can ***set the index*** by yourself of this array as you can see that i have set it.
This is the var_dump of the $_POST array to make it more crystal clear for you :

```
array(2) {
  ["questions"]=>
  array(2) {
    [2]=>
    string(5) "world" 
    [1]=>
    string(5) "hello"
  }
  ["submit"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Hope that clears your confusion . Modify it as per you need .Happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure in PHP and HTML you would do something like this:

```
<?
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    echo "<input type=text name='qa[$i][question]'>";
    echo "<input type=text name='qa[$i][answer]'>";
    echo "<input type=text name='qa[$i][date]'>";
}
?>
```

But as it sounds like you're looking to post the values without a browser, you can simply construct your post string manually and use PHP's curl support.

Generally, you would construct the POST string by looping through the available values, and calling `urlencode` to encode the POST string properly.

```
<?
$poststr = "qa[0][question]=some+question&qa[0][answer]=some+anser&qa[0][date]=2012-10-02&qa[1][question]=another+question&qa[1][answer]=another+answer&qa[1][date]=2012-09-27";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $poststr);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Then to get the values (for either method above)

```
<?
$answer_array = $_POST['qa'];
?>
```

`$answer_array` will be formatted basically like follows:

```
$answer_array = array(
   0 => array(
      "question"=>"some question",
      "answer"=>"some answer",
      "date"=>"2012-10-02"),
   1 => array(
      "question"=>"another question",
      "answer"=>"another answer",
      "date"=>"2012-09-27")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make each form element name an array like such

```
<input type='text' name='question[]' />
<input type='text' name='answer[]' />
<input type='text name='date[]'/>
```

Now you can repeat these form elements as many times as necessary, and each value will be stored as a position in an array. For example if you had 5 questions, you could access the fifth question value like:

```
<?php 
    $questions = $_POST['question];
    $fifth_question = $questions[4] //arrays start at position 0 so 4 would be the 5th position
```

You could also loop through each form elements array and create a multidimensional array like to requested above. That would look like:

```
<?php
    $questions = $_POST[question'];
    $answers = $_POST['answer'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $combined = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($questions); $i++_
    {
         $combined[] = array('question'=> $questions[$i], 
                             'answer'=>$answers[$i], 'date'=>$dates[$i]);
    }
```

Hope this helped.